# Proving or disproving that an inequality implies another inequality.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, absolute-value

I am wondering if $|a| > |b|$ implies $|\frac{b+b^{2}}{a+a^{2}}| < 1$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers. I have tested numerically with many cases and I have found this to be true in all of my testing.

We know that $|\frac{b+b^{2}}{a+a^{2}}| < 1$ is equivalent to saying $|a + a^{2}| > |b + b^{2}|$, and I believe this to be always true if $|a| > |b|$, but I am not sure how I would prove this easily.

One might be able to do a proof by cases, by checking each case $a > 1, 1 \geq a > 0, 0 > a \geq -1, -1 > a$ with each case $b \geq 1, 1 > b \geq 0, 0 \geq b > -1, -1 \geq b$, but this is tedious and there is probably a more elegant way (Possibly using the triangle inequality in some way?).

I appreciate any response.

EDIT:
I have asked another question directly related to this one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1670327/cases-in-which-a-certain-inequality-holds-true). Once again I would greatly appreciate responses to this question as well.

EDIT 2:
I have asked a second question directly related to this one [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1672191/proving-an-inequality-given-some-conditions). This one, we have the added restriction that $a > 0$. I would greatly appreciate responses to this question as well.

Comment: Wouldn't something like $$a = -1.01,\ b = 1$$ be a counterexample?

Comment: It looks to be the case. In my testing I seemed to be misusing the absolute value and was "distributing" it like $|a + a^{2}| = |a| + |a^{2}|$, but this only works when $a$ and $a^{2}$ are of the same sign. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Counter-example:** Take
$$
a_n = -\frac{1}{n}
$$
and
$$
b_n = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^{2}}.
$$
Then for all $n$ one has $\lvert b_n \rvert < \lvert a_n\rvert$, but
$$
\left\lvert \frac{b_n+b_n^2}{a_n+a_n^2} \right\rvert
=
\frac{\frac{1}{n} - \frac{2}{n^{3}} + o\left(\frac{1}{n^{3}}\right)}{\frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n^2}} = 1+\frac{1}{n} + o\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) > 1
$$
the inequality holding for $n$ big enough.

Answer (score 1):

You have $|b|/|a| < 1$ ($a\neq 0$). Hence $b^2 < a^2$ and thus $1+b^2 < 1+a^2$. Equivalently,
$$
\frac{1+b^2}{1+a^2} < 1.
$$
Now, this implies
$$
\left|\frac{b+b^3}{a+a^3}\right| = \frac{|b|}{|a|}\frac{1+b^2}{1+a^2} < 1,
$$
since both factors are $< 1$. So, your result is false, but it holds when you replace 2 by 3 in the exponent.

Comment: This is also an excellent response. Thank you.

Comment: Hey mouse. You can upvote excellent responses. ;o)

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp It does give an alternative (and correct) inequality, but why does it prove the original (which is indeed false) to actually be false? ("So, your result is false")

Comment: I need 15 reputation before my upvotes can be displayed publicly, sorry. Thank you once again.

Comment: Yuck... This system... Thanks anyway, mouse.

Answer (score 1):

Take $a=-0.6$ and $b=-0.5$. Then $|a|=0.6 > 0.5 = |b|$ but $|a+a^2|=0.24 < 0.25=|b+b^2|$.

Looking at the graph of $y=|x+x^2|$ below, we see that it is increasing for $x\in [-1,-0.5]$ when $x<0$. Hence the counter-example.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response. When you say that the graph is increasing for $x \in [-1, 0.5]$, do you mean $x \in [-1, -0.5]$?

Comment: @m0use, yes, fixed, thanks.