# Cases in which a certain inequality holds true.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, inequality, absolute-value

I previously asked [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1669521/proving-or-disproving-that-an-inequality-implies-another-inequality) on this forum, and have been demonstrated counterexamples to the claim that $|a| > |b|$ implies $\big|\frac{b+b^{2}}{a+a^{2}}\big| < 1$, which I had previously thought to be the case. I am now wondering, for which values of $a$ and $b$ is our claim true, and for which values is our claim false. For example, our claim is obviously true for $a \geq 1, b \geq 1$, and is obviously true for $a \leq 1, b \leq 1$. An example where our claim is false would be for $a = -1.01, b = 1$. Knowing precisely where our claim holds true is of great interest to me for a scientific problem I am looking at, so a formal argument would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You could try a [graphing calculator](http://desmos.com/calculator). I made [this](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mis0qgr1lh) right now, with $y$ as $a$ and $x$ as $b$. The overlap shows what you want.

Comment: @shardulc Very nice, gives the result immediately.

Comment: Thank you, this is exactly what I was looking for.